# Why doesn't the “Clone or download” button copy its URL to my primary selection?

Tags: linux, firefox, github, clipboard

On Linux (really on X11) there are multiple kinds of selection.

When I click the clipboard button on a Github "Clone or download" popup using Firefox the clone URL gets copy to the clipboard.

It does not get "copied" into the primary selection.

This annoys me, since I am used to select things with the left mouse and then pasted them with my middle mouse button. In this popup however I am forced to use the CTRL+V method to paste.

Is this a deliberate decision or a bug? I believe that it used to work some time ago?!

If it is a bug:

Is this a Firefox bug, a GTK+ bug, a Github bug or what? Where would I start looking for this problem?

Comment: What happens if you press both left and right buttons after you’ve copied it https://superuser.com/questions/80370/how-to-activate-the-paste-when-pressing-both-mouse-buttons-in-ubuntu

Comment: bestinamir: the primary selection works just fine for everything else, it just does not work for githubs repo urls